# How to remove an element and replace with another in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find and replace an element in an array. Is there any single php function for this?

Comment: Can you specify what the input is and  what output you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

See example

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, -2, 1, array("orange", "maroon"));
// $input is now array("red", "green", "orange", "maroon","yellow")
```

Comment: Your solution does not solve the problem of finding the element to be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any simple function for finding and replacing in arrays, but you could always do something like:

```
$key = array_search($oldValue, $myArray);
if ($key) $myArray[$key] = $newValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php
$myArray = array("John","William","Henry","Tom","Peter");
$newArray = array_splice($myArray, 2, 1, "Susan");
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - $value <br />";
}
?>
```